# Use Multiple DataSource(With CosmosDB) In Spring boot JPA

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I'm setting up kind of API with Spring boot, jpa.
At First, I made one CosmosDB and put all things together.
However, now I want to use multiple database one for user with MySQL & one for merchandise with CosmosDB.
How can I make proper config?

In formal case If I want to use multiple datasource in Spring boot with JPA
(For Example, Use MySQL For UserInfo & Use h2 for merchandise data
or
 Use MySQL For UserInfo & Use PostgreSQL for merchandise data
or)
I set the properties & just make two Kinds of Config like this
And It works fine.

```java
@configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"====.repository"})
public class CustomerDataSourceConfig {

    @primary
    @bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "====.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @primary
    @bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @qualifier("dataSource")           DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .packages("=====.domain")
    .persistenceUnit("customer")
    .build();
    }

    @primary
    @bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory     entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

But If I want to use Multiple DataSource(With CosmosDB) this kind of work doesn't work anymore.
I should make different kind of config for CosmosDB?
or
Is there any way I can use multiple datasource with CosmosDB?
(ex. Use MySQL For UserInfo & Use CosmosDB for merchandise data)

thx.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases this link may help you..........

Comment: Hi, thx U for comment I already try the link you sent. upper codes are basically same with the link. Howerver CosmosDB use EnableDocumentDbRepositories not EnableJpaRepositories. It does not have entityManagerFactory, transactionManagerRef. So, I want to know how can I make correct EnableDocumentDbRepositories config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
below is my github issue.
so someone want to know the answer.
plz check it.

https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/403

Comment: Is there any way we can use same model objects for both cosmos and postgres